# How to forward a subdomain to a new port on the same IP address using Apache?

Tags: apache, dns, web, subdomain, portforwarding

I have a NAS/Server running at home 24/7 and run many different services on it.  I have got a domain name pointing to it now, and was wondering if it would be possible to create sub-domains that point to different ports for different services.  For example:

- http://subsonic.mydomain.com --> XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:4040
- http://minecraft.mydomain.com --> XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:25565
- http://files.mydomain.com --> XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:4082

I have a single D-LINK router that currently port forwards all these ports to my NAS/Server whose IP is 192.168.0.104.

EDIT: The server is running Ubuntu 12.04.

What service or proxy do I need to run that can recognize the sub domain and route the traffic accordingly?  Or could I use apache virtual hosts to handle this, because these subdomains will come in on port 80, which apache is listening to?  Or does virtual hosts not work like this?

Any information, ideas, or tips would be helpful/useful.

Comment: I believe this is a valid question, and have flagged it for moderator intervention. It should be reopened.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are two ways to do this. You could use the VirtualHost section of your `httpd.conf` or you could do it in your `.htaccess`. (assuming that the subdomains resolve to the same IP as your webserver)

In `httpd.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subsonic.mydomain.com
    redirect / http://mydomain.com:4040/
</VirtualHost>
```

In `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subsonic\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com:4040/$1 [R=301]
```

Documentation:
 - [Guide to creating name-based virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html)
 - [Core](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html), including [VirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#virtualhost) and [NameVirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost)
 - [Redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect)
 - [mod_rewrite guide](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite)

Comment: Is it actually redirecting (because of R=301 which seems to be the Move Permantently http status code)? Or is it displaying the contents of the site?
In my case I wanted to achieve the second scenario.