# running apache with nginx on different ports + hosts file

Tags: apache, nginx, hosts

I have apache running on port 80 and nginx on port 81. Now i want to run two sites:

1. site1.com (on apache)
2. site2.com (on nginx)

for the first one I made a simple entry in /etc/hosts file like : 127.0.0.1 site1.com

Now for site2 I tried: 127.0.0.1:81 site2.com
This doesn't work as port numbers are not allowed in hosts file.

I have no clues as to how to get this accomplished.

Comment: Use htaccess to change port for second domain..? Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12732965/2611927

Comment: this actually redirects to site2.com:81, which is not what i need. I want something which stays on site2.com and use port 81 instead of 80

Comment: You could put nginx as primary server to port 80 and pass through to apache if domain is site1.com check this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-configure-nginx-as-a-front-end-proxy-for-apache

Comment: What you need is apache to use the same name `site2.com` and proxy it to port 81, but then if a proxy is involved then why not use ngixn as the frontend like @Hardy suggested and let it proxy to apache, should improve memory usage when loading apache sites ( if you load assets directly from nginx instead of apache )