# Redirect Apache Subdomain:80 to 8096

Tags: linux, bash, apache, redirect, port

I have a domain..
    sub.example.com, which you can reach via port 80.

Everytime a user is searching for that Domain, I want to get an `redirect to port 8096`, but the user should not realize that.

Does anyone have a suggestion for this how to configure a `vHost`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to forward a subdomain to a new port on the same IP address?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715195/how-to-forward-a-subdomain-to-a-new-port-on-the-same-ip-address)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use redirect to port 80 to 8096 or use Proxy configuration.

For me the better is the Proxy because the client not view your port 8096 in his web browser

**Example to Proxy configuration :**

Firts make sure apache listen on port 8096 :

```
netstat -laputen|grep 8096
```

If you have no reply, check Listen port in  /etc/apache2/ports.conf :

> Listen 8096

Restart apache and recheck LISTEN in netstat

```
service apache2 restart
netstat -laputen|grep 8096
```

**If is not apache who listen the port 8096, you just need to create vhost to listen on port 80, not 8096**

Enable proxy module in apache2 :

```
a2enmod proxy proxy_http
```

Restart apache :

```
service apache2 restart
```

Create Virtual Host :

> /etc/apache2/sites-available/sub2_example_com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # Just listen to sub2.example.com, the others sub-domain going to the default Vhost
        ServerName sub2.example.com

        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8096/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8096/
</VirtualHost>

# Just if is not another app who listening to port 8096
<VirtualHost *:8096>
        ServerName sub2.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/my_website

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/my_website_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/my_website_access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Enable Virtual Host :

```
a2ensite sub2_example_com.conf
```

Reload Apache :

```
service apache2 reload
```

Open your web browser in sub2.example.com , apache redirect all request in port 8096

Doc apache :
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html